# Unable to log in to open directory account

Tags: network, osx-server, network-user

I'm in the process of setting up my Mac Mini with Lion server. Everything appears to be working fine on the server, but I'm having problems logging into any open directory account that has a network share set as the home folder. If I change the users home folder to just a local folder, I can log in fine. I've confirmed my client is correctly connected to the directory server, because if I enter the password incorrectly, I get the password incorrect error.

The error I get when I attempt to log into the account is this, in a message box: "**You are unable to log into the user account "testaccount" at this time.** Logging in to the account failed because an error occurred."

I can't even log into "testaccount" locally from the server, I get the same error.

Is there some step I'm missing?

Comment: I, too, am having this problem, except that local login to the 10.7.2 server works, and login through a 10.7.2 client does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to solve this, though perhaps not the "right" way. Changing the server to a local server with the address `myserver.local` instead of `myserver.com` fixed the issue with me. I then just use a dynamic DNS service to point my domain to my IP. Now everything works correctly and I can login on both the client and the server.

Comment: Did you ever figure out exactly why this worked? Did it cause any other problems later down the road?